# How do you open 2 windowgroups from SwiftUI button on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I have an app where I have a need where a button will open two windows.  In the App struct I have the two window groups setup

```
@main
struct myApp: App {

  var body : some Scene {

      WindowGroup() {
         WelcomeView()
      }

      WindowGroup("FirstViewGroup") {

        FirstView()
        
      }
      .handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "FirstViewGroup"))

      WindowGroup("SecondViewGroup") {
        SecondView()
      }
      .handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "SecondViewGroup"))
  }
}
```

In the WelcomeView I have the following button action:

```
Button {
   if let firstURL = URL(string: "myApp://FirstViewGroup"), let secondURL = URL(string: "myApp://SecondViewGroup") {
      NSWorkspace.shared.open(firstURL)
      NSWorkspace.shared.open(secondURL)
   }
} label: {
  Text("Open Windows")
}
```

When I comment out one of the NSWorkspace.shared.open lines in the button action, the appropriate window opens. But when I have two sequential NSWorkspace.shared.open calls, I only get the first.  Ideas?  I have the URL Types in info.plist set correctly (since each window opens successfully when each is called individually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open second URL in next event loop, like

```
Button {
   if let firstURL = URL(string: "myApp://FirstViewGroup"), let secondURL = URL(string: "myApp://SecondViewGroup") {
      NSWorkspace.shared.open(firstURL)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         NSWorkspace.shared.open(secondURL)   // << here !!
      }
   }
} label: {
  Text("Open Windows")
}
```